# jquery replaceWith doesn't work for some reason

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I've got this totally simple code for changing one image `(#form1)` with another `(#form2)` when clicking on `#third`, which doesn't seem to work.

I've thought maybe it's because I've already used `$(document).ready` before but now I'm reading it's fine to use it several times.

So what is wrong? Could someone help me out?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#form2").hide();
      $("#third").click(function() { 
        $("#form1").replaceWith("#form2");
      });
    });
```

Comment: `$('#form2').show();`

Answer (score 3):

Pass the element to [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), not the selector string:

```
$("#form1").replaceWith($("#form2"));
//                      ^^        ^ was missing
```

The argument to [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) can be a HTML string, DOM element or jQuery element, but it should never be the selector string like you have.

Answer (score 3):

Because you replace form with a string not with an object

`$("#form1").replaceWith($("#form2"));`